# I want to rename the classname after compiling a .java file in cmd

Tags: java, cmd, compilation

Is there a command to do this? For example, in C#, you can rename the .exe file after compiling by using the `/out: [name-of-file].exe`.

Comment: why do you want to so this?

Comment: javac -d bin src/foo/bar/*.java

i am sure that you can change the destination of the .class that generate but not sure of the renaming it.

Answer (score 0):

The name of a `.java` file must be the same as the name of the public class defined inside of it.
Once a `.java` is compiled into a `.class`, the name of the class file must also remain the same as the public class's name. This cannot be changed without renaming the class in the `.java`, renaming the `.java` to be the same as the new class name, and then recompiling into a `.class`.

C# does not have this restriction, and allows you to name your `.cs` whatever you like, regardless of the name of the class defined inside of it.